# How to access from Windows 10 the Oracle VM VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I am trying to access one of two databases from a short Java program from which excerpts are enlisted below. On my laptop, eclipse and MySQL are deployed. The code accesses MySQL without a problem. HSQLDB, however, is installed on the Oracle VM VirtualBox.

```
>ipconfig

Windows-IP-Konfiguration


Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::b598:af5e:ee50:42f%10
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter LAN-Verbindung* 2:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter LAN-Verbindung* 1:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: kabsi.at
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::5d9a:a1d2:300c:89e0%4
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.27
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet-Adapter Bluetooth-Netzwerkverbindung:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
```

How can I find the IP address of the VM? Both machines are Windows 10. Does `ipconfig` show this address to me? I tried `192.168.56.1`, but it didn't work.

**Edit:**
I executed `ipconfig` on the VM & got the following "answer":

```
C:\Users\User>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : kabsi.at
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::185e:4a15:f4bc:3566%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2

C:\Users\User>
```

But my Java code that successfully "talks" to the MySQL server installed on the host seems unable to access the HSQLDB on the VM:

```
Unable to connect to server at "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://10.0.2.15:9001/shop" with user "SA".
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Please note that I not only access the IP of the VM but a specific (default) port of the HSQLDB. How can I differentiate between an unsuccessful try reaching the VM and an unsuccessful try to access a port on the VM?

Here are some settings I did to the VM recommended by others on forums:
[image: Port forwarding for the VM VirtualBox]

Comment: FYI: VirtualBox is not a VMware product.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find the IP address of the VM?

If you need to know the address assigned to the VM, that is typically discovered in the VM itself (e.g. run `ipconfig` there).

> Does `ipconfig` show this address to me? I tried `192.168.56.1`, but it didn't work.

`ipconfig` shows the addresses assigned to adapters for that particular machine. `192.168.56.1` is a private network address for a Virtualbox Host-only adapter. That is, this is the address of the *host* in VirtualBox from the VM's perspective (i.e. if your database was located on your host, your virtual machines would send requests to `192.168.56.1`).

---

**Notes**

You may also want to consider a bridged adapter or NAT adapter in VirtualBox. Of the two, a bridged adapter is slightly easier to configure. Essentially, you assign your PC's network card to a VirtualBox adapter and it gets an address from your DHCP provider and can then be accessed like any other computer on the network.

You may also want to have a look at the [official VirtualBox documentation on Virtual Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see the **Edit** above…